# Is there any way to create and add a Cookie to a Response inside a Filter?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have a Filter and a Servlet. I am trying to create a Cookie and add it to the Response in the Filter after the "chain.doFilter" method.

*The Cookie needs to be created and added to the Response after the "chain.doFilter" method because its value depends on some information coming from the Response.

I did some research and found that creating a Wrapper for the Response (before the doFilter method) would allow me to achieve this but it is not working, I am able to add the Cookie to the Wrapper but when checking in the browser the Cookie is not there.

Comment: the same question and same scenario. @cricardo did you get any solution for this??

Answer (score 1):

To add cookie you have to use HttpServletResponse class in doFilter method.
Here is an example:

```
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

Comment: First, the "doFilter" method has ServletRequest and ServletResponse as argument types. Also, as I said I need to add the Cookie after the "chain.doFilter" method.

Comment: You could add a filter with the name CockieFilter and set up a sequence of execution in your application. In case you are using javax.servlet.Filter you can cast ServletRequest to  HttpServletRequest. It will work in case you are sending http requests to your application.

Comment: The Cookie needs to be created and added to the Response after the "chain.doFilter" method because its value depends on some information coming from the Response.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpServletResponse httpResp=(HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;
Cookie myCookie=new Cookie("test","");
myCookie.setValue("testValue");
myCookie.setPath("/");
myCookie.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
httpResp.addCookie(myCookie);
filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
```

> Try it this way this can add cookies in your browser and also get a
>   response from it

Comment: What I am looking for is to add a Cookie to the servletResponse AFTER the filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse); executes.